# Selenium - sendKeys to element Select

Tags: selenium, sendkeys

As title says. It's easy to send keys to WebElement, since it has such method, but how to send them to an element of **Select** class  (from package  org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select).

Comment: You can't send keys to `Select` class. Maybe you should explain what you are 
actually want to achieve and add your code, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Hello Guy:)

I'm precticing Selenium on site [link](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/jquery-dropdown-search-demo.html) I want to type several first letters of the country, so that the country will appear as a tip.

Comment: The actual drop down is in `<span>` tag, you can't use `Select` class for this. There is a `<select>` tag, however it hidden therefor unusable. Basically you need to click on the drop down and wait for the input field to appear. You can send keys to that field after you locate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
driver.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/jquery-dropdown-search-demo.html");
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/span[1]/span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/span/span/span[1]/input")).sendKeys("India");
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
By option = By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'India')]");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(option));
driver.findElement(option).click();
```

Please note that the xpath used here are not well formed. Kindly change that accordingly

Comment: Hi, you don't need explicit wait because element come into existence after your click, so your implicit wait is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Write this code, it would work for you

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/jquery-dropdown-search-demo.html");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[aria-labelledby='select2-country-container']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.select2-search__field:nth-of-type(1)")).sendKeys("Australia");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='Australia']")).click();
```